# Selenium / Java : Unable to locate element on a ion search popup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

We are trying to automate a flow and it require a click + sign on a below popup window.
We have tried xpath locator but element is not getting located.
and below we get below error:

```
error : org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <ion-icon color="gray-900" name="ios-add-circle-outline" role="img" class="icon icon-ios icon-ios-gray-900 ion-ios-add-circle-outline" aria-label="add circle-outline"></ion-icon> is not clickable at point (1135, 195). Other element would receive the click: <span class="button-inner">...</span>
```

[image]

Element locator code is

[image]

We are using following code in our step definition for it:

Element locator:

> ```
> @FindBy (xpath = "//*[@name='ios-add-circle-outline']")
> private WebElement plusIcon;
> ```

To click below code is being used by us.
method ()

```
> String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
> driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
> Thread.sleep(3000);
> plusIcon.click();
```

Comment: target the span or the button instead... button's probably where the event handler is...

Answer (score 0):

Action class used to overcome above issue.

```
> Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
> builder.moveToElement(plusIcon); 
> builder.click(); builder.perform();
```